# Referencing nested class does not style in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to reference a nested class within my html, which is under `<body>`. The issue is, is that if I were to reference body by itself in css, the background would appear. However if I try to reference my class under body, it doesn't appear. I've tried referencing it with a `.` before the class name which still doesn't work. Code below:

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <title>vxsqi-lib</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="backgroundimage"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.backgroundimage {
    background-image: url("backgroundimage/dark-night-mountains-4k-e3.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: *"I've tried referencing it with a . before the class name which still doesn't work"* You have to prefix className with a "." as a CSS selector string. It's not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
div.backgroundimage {
background-image: url("backgroundimage/dark-night-mountains-4k-e3.jpg");
background-size:cover;
background-color: white;}
```

Edit second options because wrong :(

This must be work. Let me know if doesnt